# Why does $P(X^n>x^n)$ equal $P(X>x)$?

Tags: probability-theory

I was trying to prove that for a nonnegative random varable $Y$,

$$E[Y]=\int_0^\infty P(Y>t)~dt$$

to show that, for a nonnegative random variable $X$,

$$E[X^n]=\int_0^\infty nx^{n-1}P(X>x)~dx$$

I started with:

$$E[X^n]=\int_0^\infty P(X^n>t)~dt$$

We can make a change of variables $t$ = $x^n$ and $dt = nx^{n-1}dx$, so substituting those variables to the equation above becomes:

$$E[X^n]=\int_0^\infty nx^{n-1}P(X^n>x^n)~dx$$

But why does $P(X^n>x^n)$ become $P(X>x)$?  Actually, what does the random variable $X^n$ tell us?

Comment: If $X$ takes nonnegative values and $x$ is some fixed nonnegative number, then $X^n>x^n\iff X>x$ just by applying $n$th roots. So one happens precisely when the other happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a$ and $b$ are non-negative real numbers and $u$ is a positive real number, then $$a^u>b^u\iff a>b$$

Therefore, $\{X^n>a^n\}=\{\omega\in\Omega\,:\,(X(\omega))^n>a^n\}=\{\omega\in\Omega\,:\,X(\omega)>a\}=\{X>a\}$ as **sets**.